# Calendar Functions in Bootflat

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, bootflat

I am using [Bootflat](http://bootflat.github.io/) and I couldn't find a decent documentation with sample codes. I want to use the `Calendar` element and thus far I have referred to the source code of this [link](http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html), which seems to be the only documentation. But there seems no reference for using the next and back navigation buttons of the calendar.

[image]

1. Where can I find a good documentation on `BootFlat`
2. What is the java script function to call for the `next` and `back` buttons on the calendar
3. How to give an `onClick()` for the dates so that a modal pops up.

Comment: Hello! Did you find an answer? Thank you!

Comment: I am afraid not,  we made one ourselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i know its too late for the answer but yes this may help someone so posting answer !!!

1. first of all there is no good documentation for Bootflat datepicker except from their official [site here...](http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html)
2. Then moving to the datepicker of bootflat, Bootflat is providing us only good style for the calendar, if we want to use calendar then we can use the style of bootflat for our calendar but bootflat itself is not providing any javascript method for the next and back months or onClick months popup or anything like that
3. ### Bootflat Datepicker--

   I have created one datepicker using Bootflat theme for the angular2 for myself,  here you found the functionality of next and back month, Today date selected, and pop over over the dates.
   Look at here....

> https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

Comment: It would be nice if you could share some screenshots at Git Repo. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! i have updated the git repo you can check the updated the repo with readme.md !